# What would be an efficient way of generating Plancast-style short URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, url

Plancast generate short URLs like `http://plancast.com/p/3e9c` for event pages.

URL hashes don't seem sequential, but they're probably not completely random either.

Here are a few ones for example: `3sro`, `3fsz`, `3k4f`, `382n`, `3c5x`, etc.

What would be an efficient way of deterministically generating such hashes from PHP and MySQL, with the appearance of being randomly generated?

Comment: What would be the advantage of an "appearance of being randomly generated" when they're too short to effectively prevent people from guessing valid ones?

Comment: Well, it looks cooler, and keeps people from having a way to sequentially order my pages (page `103` was created before page `142`, etc.)

Comment: They could be sequential as they are just database keys. The alphanumeric ASCII 8-bit characters range is: [0x30 - 0x39, 0x41 - 0x5a, 0x60 - 0x7a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We set up those URLs so that last piece is simply the ID of the event in our database converted to base 36. They only appear random because they are in that base, but in fact, they are incrementing one at a time as we get new events in the system.

Comment: I'm curious.. how'd you find this question? :)

Comment: Google Alerts for "plancast" =)

Comment: Good thing Stack Overflow is nicely indexed then ;)

Comment: That means you have something like 200k events now, right?

One additional remark: they also don't seem sequential at first because they're ordered by date/time of the event itself, not its creation.